# Do I need to register my app in app store or apple development before start coing the App

Tags: ios, app-store

I am working on my first iOS app .I have enrolled my company in the Apple development program.But I didn't mention anything about the app that I am going to develop.
My app might take 6 more months to complete the coding stage. I am just wondering do I need to report my app somewhere in the Apple development program at the development stage.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No. Don't worry about anything until it's done.

Comment: @rmaddy Has it ceased to be the case that product names must be unique? Otherwise that's something somebody might like to contemplate for a few seconds. But otherwise, no, Apple doesn't care when you first communicate your plans, you can develop as many things as you like for as long as you like without registering any of them.

Comment: thank you for your reply. was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least enter some app metadata, including your preferred app name into iTunes Connect.  Otherwise, some other developer might take that app name first, while your app is still in development.  Entering an app's name early reduces the possibility that you would then have to change the app's name (and documentation and marketing materials, etc.) at the last minute (because that app name is already in use, and Apple usually disallows exact duplicates).